# SharePoint 2013 cancel Workflow but page workflow status unchanged

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-workflow

I have created a custom workflow solution that I deployed to my SharePoint publishing site.
Using CSOM and C#, I have written some server side code that will cancel a running workflow on a publishing page.  I know my code works because the workflow completes and I have sent a payload message to my workflow which shows up in the logs.

But when I open my site in a browser and navigate to the /pages/forms/Allitems.aspx page, I see a list of pages within that site.

So far so good.
But a closer look shows the approval status column of draft.

Why is that as I thought canceling the workflow would update the page's approval status column automatically.

Tom

Answer (score 0):

Cancelling a workflow does not change the approval status column. You can first update the status, and then cancel your workflow.